# Pass value by reference in pthread

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void* func(void*);

int main()
{
    int numb = 0;
    pthread_t pid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    pthread_create(&pid, &attr, func, (void*)&numb);    
    printf("%s%d\n", "Number: ", numb);

    return 0;
}

//..............defintation...............

void* func(void* data)
{
    int* numb = (int*)data;
    *numb = 1000;
}
```

I want to pass the number to the function "func" by reference. I did so by passing the address of the number "(void*)&numb". I changed the value to 1000 in the function and printed the value in main, but the output is 0 instead of 1000.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You have a race condition - and `main` won

Comment: @EdHeal: Please don't write answers in comments. Comments are not subject to all the usual oversight of the answers section: downvotes, rep, reviews, suggested edits, bounties, contribution to question management (rules on some things that can happen to questions depend on whether an answer is present) etc _Answers belong in the answer section. ONLY._

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet - I did not think my comment can be justified as an answer - but you get +1 for doing this for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic race condition.

Your computer got to the `printf` in main before it got to the `*numb = 1000` in `func`.

You will need a condition variable or some other form of concurrency primitive in order to synchronise access to this datum.

These are the very basics of multi-threaded programming, so you should read a book on the subject rather than guessing.